# float shown as float, but integer as integer in python

Tags: python, floating-point, integer

so i'm new here.. this is a simple thing but i can't find the answer anywhere..

i want user can input float, but if the user input integer it will shown as integer,not float..

```
x = float(input('input any number : '))
print(x)
```

if the user input 5

```
output : 5.0
```

what i want it display only 5 (without decimal point).. but the user can still input float number..

```
input => output
5.3 => 5.3
5 => 5
```

Comment: i already get the answer! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### With float.is_integer()

```py
x = float(input())
print(int(x) if x.is_integer() else x)
```

#### With [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) and formatting

```py
x = float(input())
print(f'{x:g}')
```

output:

```
>>> 5.3
5.3
>>> 5
5
```

Answer (score 1):

you may give [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) (instead of `float`) a try (depending on what else you want to do with that number):

```
from decimal import Decimal

user_input = "5"
x = Decimal(user_input)
print(x) # 5

user_input = "5.3"
x = Decimal(user_input)
print(x)  # 5.3
```

Comment: i want to make simple calculator.. it's just confusing when user input single digit number but the decimal point appear.. but if my calculator can't calculate float it will be a problem too.. i'm new in coding(only 1 month) i haven't learn much about module.. but i'll try to learn it.. thank you so much!

Comment: you **can** calculate with `Decimal`s.

Answer (score 1):

I was a little confused by the wording of your question, but what I think you're saying is that if a user inputs an integer, you want it to be treated (or displayed) as an integer, but if the user inputs a float, then you want it to be treated (or displayed) as a float.

The best option here would be to use the `is_integer()` method available to floats (I know its available in python 3 but not sure about python 2)

```py
>>> 1.4.is_integer()
False

>>> 1.0.is_integer()
True

>>> x = 12.0
>>> x.is_integer()
True
```

So using your original example, you could do this:

```
x = float(input('input any number : '))
x = int(x) if x.is_integer() else x
print(x)
```

Be warned, this puts a lot of trust in your users to only input a float or int. If they were to put 'foo' then your program will raise a `ValueError` Exception, so don't forget to either convert the value to float (or int) once you have checked it, or add this into a loop containing try-exception statements.

Since Python was built around try-except causes for exactly this sort of thing, here is a full example using a try-except block, which only moves on once the user has inputted a valid value:

```py
While True:
    try:
        x = float(input('input any number : '))
        x = int(x) if x.is_integer() else x
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Invalid Numerical Value (must be float or integer)"

print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following:

```
'%g'%(5.0)
```

For your case it will be as follows:

```
x = float(input('input any number : '))
print('%g'%(x))
```

Using `.format`:

```
x = float(input('input any number : '))
print('{0:g}'.format(x))
```